# Pydb compilation issue for python 3.3 as user with limited access rights

Tags: python, unix, installation, sudo

I am trying to compile pydb for python 3.3, but I have limited access right on my environment.
To avoid accessing forbidden areas, I used the following *configure* command:

```
./configure --prefix=/my/prefix
   --with-python=/my/python/path/python3.3
   --with-site-packages=/my/site/package/path/mysite-packages
```

But *configure* complains about the version of *python*:

**checking whether /sw/freetools/python/3.3.0/Linux/rh5/x86_64/bin/python version >= 2.4.0... configure: error: too old**

I didn't have the issue when compiling for python 2.7.2.

Could someone help me to solve this installation issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't `--with--python` be `--with-python`?

Comment: You are right! That's a little bit better now. I updated the question since I have a new issue...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile (in cygwin) like this:

```
PYTHON=python3 ./configure --with-site-packages=/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```